# Algorithm to find the minimum among the distances between pairs of vertices of a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

A tree is given whose every vertex is initially coloured `white`.

Now, the vertices are coloured `black` one by one, and the aim is to find, after colouring every new vertex, the minimum among the distances between all possible pairs of `black` vertices.

It should be noted that the distance between a pair of vertices is the number of edges on the path between them.

---

To solve this problem, I've used an array `min_dist[]` (0-based indexing) such that `min_dist[u]` is the distance of vertex `u` from the nearest `black` vertex. Then, I've used a depth-first search on the graph after colouring every new vertex.

Let `G` represent the tree and `c[]` be the array representing the vertices to be coloured `black` in order.

```
SOLVE(G, c)
1. ans = +(infinity)
2. for (i = 0 to (|G.V| - 1))
3.     min_dist[i] = +(infinity)
4. for (i = 0 to (|G.V| - 1))
5.     min_dist[c[i]] = 0
6.     DFS(G, ans, min_dist, c[i], -1)
7.     print ans
```

```
DFS(G, ans, min_dist, v, parent)
1. for (each vertex child in G.Adj[v])
2.     if (child == parent)
3.         continue
4.     if (min_dist[child] > min_dist[v] + 1)
5.         min_dist[child] = min_dist[v] + 1
6.         DFS(G, ans, min_dist, child, v);
7.     else if (ans > min_dist[child] + min_dist[v] + 1)
8.         ans = (min_dist[child] + min_dist[v] + 1)
```

---

Now, I think that my algorithm is correct, but the official solution to this problem is a slightly modified version of my algorithm where they've added an extra check for termination in the DFS.

```
DFS(G, ans, min_dist, v, parent)
1. if (min_dist[v] >= ans)
2.     return
3. for (each vertex child in G.Adj[v])
   ...
```

I need help in verifying the correctness of this modified version.

I've taken many examples and in all of those, this modified version produces the correct answers. (https://kushagrj.github.io/Codeforces-Round-847-Div-3-Problem-F/)

Answer (score 0):

So you have the optimization where you don't DFS into a child unless the child's `min_dist` was updated. Using the same reasoning, we can derive the extra test.

Suppose that the problem had an extra parameter θ, and you were to determine whether `ans` < θ. By tedious induction, if DFS is called when `min_dist[v]` ≥ θ−1, then it only writes values ≥ θ to `min_dist`. The only other reads would be to evaluate < θ, so you could restrict the distance labels to 0...θ, making θ effectively ∞. Then the no-update optimization kicks in.

The other idea is that you can repeatedly lower θ to the current best value of `ans`, effectively using `ans` as θ.